# Bat file to compare folders

Tags: batch-file

I'm looking to create a bat file to compare local folders from a dir command with folders on a server, and then delete the local folders if they do not exist on the server. Additionally, it is having issues with directories including spaces, but I have not looked into this yet.

My current code is not working correctly. Could anyone provide some guidance please?

Code:

```
REM Search local directories for files, delete if not present on server
set n=0
set count=0
for /f %%a in ('dir /a:d /b %_Entry_Local_Status60_path%') do (
set folder[!n!]=%%a
set /A a+=1
set /A n+=1
set /A count+=1
) 

set n=0
for /L %%a in (0,1,%count%) do (
echo !folder[%n%]!
if not exist %_Entry_Network_Status60_path%\!folder[%n%]! rmdir %_Entry_Local_Status60_path%\!folder[%n%]!
set /A n+=1
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at the `robocopy` command. I think `robocopy _source_ _target_ /purge` does exactly what you want.

Comment: @statosdotcom I don't get what you're saying?

Comment: @statosdotcom??? `robocopy` is a cmd command. You can use it in a batch file or in the pure command line.

Comment: Sorry Gerhard and Michael, and thank you. I was wrong with my comment.

Comment: That sounds exactly like what I need, I'll give it a go.

Comment: Works fine. I used /e to include all subfolders as well. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @JPToadstool You're welcome. Please mark my answer as a solution.

Answer (score 3):

I use the following to compare files within different folders and delete the ones from first folder which does not exists on second one. With some adaptation probably you could use something similar with folders and not files. This is based on FC and you have to provide the two absolute paths:

```
echo off   
set "Folder1=path\to\Folder1"
set "Folder2=path\to\Folder2"

for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b "%folder2%"') do (
    if not exist "%folder1%\%%F" (
        fc /b "%folder1%\%%F" "%folder2%\%%F"
        if "%errorlevel%" EQU "1" (
            del "%folder1%\%%F" && echo Deleted "%%F"
        )
    ) else (
        del "%folder1%\%%F" && echo Deleted "%%F"
    )
)
pause
Exit
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, it may come in useful in future. The robocopy command above achieves exactly what I was after though.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. Please, check Michael's answer as correct if solved your matters. If you think it was helpful, you could vote plus one too to signal another users about the functionality and usefulness. Mine too! Thanks.